# In App purchase Related things

Tags: iphone

I am new in application and am doing in app purchase in my application. There are lots of videos coming from the server side according to their two different prices.

So what can i do for this?

My question is that I have to create so many product ids for each video or is there a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create the product id for every product you wish to put on the app store. Apple checks each and every purchase made by the user on the basis of the product id you create on iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thanks for your answers,
r u confirm this that if there is 100 video then i have to create each product id means 100 product id for each and every product.

or any group in app purchase is there?

Thanks & regards
Ravi

Comment: Yes you have to create 100 product ids.. For my app i've created 57 product ids..there's no other way buddy

Answer (score 0):

If all video having same price there on the app store by IAP then you can only add one item there and display this item all time and make transactions there.

Comment: Thanks for giving me aswer;
but if there is prices diff-2 then?

Comment: then you have to add the each item there but if some video do have same price you can put the one item only and get transaction by a little change in you logic

Comment: @Ballu If only 1 item is present on the In App Purchases..how will you discriminate 100s of videos??

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a a product id for every product - so yes each video will need two product id's.

It's important to remember that if I buy a video in your app then I will be able to delete the app, and re-install it and re-download the video for free - iTunes will recognise that I have already bought it and give it to me for free.

This is only be possible if every product has a unique id - so there is no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is this: I have to buy more than 100 items and when a user taps two items I just pick the one ID with the count and multiply the cost against the counted object.  When you have to buy one by one just forget the count and pick the price of the product. It works for me with simple logic.

```
(void)requestProductData {
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects: @"com.Image.image3", nil]];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
//[request release];
}
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {


if([response.products count] > 0) {
SKProduct *productData = (SKProduct *)[response.products objectAtIndex:0];
NSInteger nQty = [appDelegate.arrSelImages count];
SKMutablePayment *myPayment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:productData];
myPayment.quantity = nQty;
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:myPayment];
}
else {
[self removeLoadingView];
}
[request release];

}
```

Comment: Thanks 4 your replaying


Thanks for your replaying:

if there is some video with same price and another is different prices then what should we do,suppose:

product id                            price

Tiger                                        1$
Peacock                                   2$
Bear                                         3$
Rat                                           4$
Elephant                                   5$

Panther                                        1$
Rabbit                                           2$


Then what should we do?


Thanks

Comment: actually i put the code if you have same price of some item then you don't need to put 100 videos there on the app setting you can put the total different no of price video id and when you tap to purchase just find out the id and price and apply the code above and if you have all the different price for each item then you have to write different id for each element. Ravi actually this was written by me when i was working upon it unfortuanately i don't such kind of link.

Comment: Thanks dear,
your code is perfectly fine from your side?
so i think this is very helpful for me.
Thanks again,
i try in my code and get back to You.

Comment: Hi Ballu ,I have one doubt,if i create 5 product id in itunes connect then how we fetch in my code with objectatindex:
SKProduct *productData = (SKProduct *)[response.products objectAtIndex:0];
Please let me know
Thanks

Comment: Actually here the flow is like this -if user just click on one video then you will get the video by its identifier but let suppose user have selected the 3 video of same price then you have to just count the video only and check their price if all the video having the price same then ask him to 3 times money that you have mention for one.Simple .But if all the video are different then you will get notified by their itune id that you have bounded video to video

Comment: the code which will work as logic i put it here remain you have to think according to your app' requirment i just suggest a gud way if you are not able to work with this one please go ahead with your one and add each video id on the app store .

Comment: Hi Ballu,
Ok i have done it,
But my next question is that,how to record the transaction.
we have to develope serverside transaction record?
if yes then how to do it.
Thanks

Comment: for recording your transaction on server please follow the tutorial with details of all things   http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

Comment: Do you know how to stop a movieplayer in middle,I am able to doing this on self performselector but if we can access slider/seek bar than whole movies play.i have to stop also from slider/seek.
Not create custom movieplayer.
below is my code look like:

float duration = mp.duration;
[mp setInitialPlaybackTime:0.0f];
        [mp setEndPlaybackTime:(.25*duration)];
[self performSelector:@selector(alertShowing) withObject:nil afterDelay:mp.endPlaybackTime];
but this can use only for some time if user not click on slider/seek,

Comment: but if user access slider or seek than whole moves play.
i dont get how to restrict from slider/seek also.

Comment: explain little in a different question it is not belongs to in app purchase